# CSS for a Wavy Footer

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend

Does anybody know how to design this kind of wavy footer in css? I'm still at the beginning and this has been a nightmare. I could get one wave right, but not all. Kindly appreciated.

For some context the whole footer should be a react component, more specific an organism, following atomic design.

[Wavy footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bq2m4.png)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know if it is what you're looking for, but you can design SVG curves in this page [Haikei](https://haikei.app)
After that, just set the background of your footer to that SVG and it is all set. Of course you can do it using pure CSS, but it is way more complicated as you have to use pseudoelements, lots of properties, and the HTML gets very confusing.
This is an example of what you can do in Haikei [image]